# What does removeAction() in google charts do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

How does the removeAction() work in google charts?

In the docs it is mentioned that `Removes the tooltip action with the requested actionID from the chart.` Does this mean that if a tooltip is opened, then if I click somewhere in the dom then calling this method will remove the tooltip? And what is `actionID` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeAction` removes a [tooltip action](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#tooltip-actions), added previously by the developer

the `actionID` parameter is the id of the action used in `setAction(action)`

to use a tooltip action, you must set an action on the chart, i.e.

```
    chart.setAction({
      id: 'increase',
      text: 'Read 20 more books',
      action: function() {
        data.setCell(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 1,
                     data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 1) + 20);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    });
```

to remove the above action from the chart...

`removeAction('increase');`